# How to appen url when using the try_files in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am starting explore nginx server to host the angular app with i18n. we are hosting couple of versions of same application. currently my incoming url is https://example.com/ui1/ and gateway trims to just https://example.com. it goes to the nginx and comes back with https://example.com/en-US but since the gateway is looking for https://example.com/ui1 it returns 502. I am trying to find a way to return it back but since I am using the try_files it returns by default so, I cannot append the path. is it something I can do other than try_files or is it something I can rewrite and from gateway I can send https://example.com/ui1/ ? I am trying to do https://example.com/ui1/ to https://example.com/ui1/en-US/index.html. Here is the current config

```
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     if ($accept_language ~ "^$") {
         set $accept_language "en-US";
     }
     rewrite ^/ui1/$ /ui1/$accept_language permanent;
     location ~ ^/ui1/(en-US|es-US|it-IT) {
        try_files $uri /$1/index.html?$args;
     }
```

Comment: You could change `/$1/index.html?$args` to `/ui1/$1/index.html?$args`.